# how to highlight text in tkinter using for loops

Tags: tkinter, highlight

trying to highlight some part of a text using tkinter tag_add widget. just not sure how to reference start and end index in tkinter. could someone tell me how to resolve this issue? without using for looops it is going to be startindex: 1.0, endindex:1.3 but how I can reference to those indexes when it comes to for loops?`

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title('highlight')
x='ABCDEFG'
text=Text(window, width=20, height=5, font=('Calibri 12'))
text.insert(INSERT, x)
for i in range(len(x)):
             text.tag_add('highlight', x[i], x[i+1])
text.tag_configure("highlight",background="OliveDrab1", foreground="black")
text.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you aware you can add the tag when the text is inserted with `text.insert(INSERT, x, "highlight")`? Or do you have a reason for needing to do it after?

Comment: above text 'ABCDEFG' is just an example. my text will be produced by for loops containing more than 500 characters that's why I need for loops and I need i to reference start and end index.

Comment: The text is irrelevant, and so is the number of characters. I still don't understand why you need a loop. In your real code, is there more code between the time you insert the text and when you want to highlight it? Using a loop is inefficient if all you're doing is highlighting text immediately after inserting it.

Comment: my codes are too long and can't paste it here but my question is more about how to reference start and end indexes. in tkinter people use 1.0 to reference line and character. how we can reference to those indexes by something like x[i] or something like that? without using tkinter, I use this code for highlighting:

Comment: user.replace(user[i], '\033[44;33m{}\033[m'.format(user[i+1])

Answer (score 0):

Since you're inserting code at the insertion point, you can get the index with the `index` method. For example, to get the insertion point immediately before inserting the string you can do something like this:

```
start_index = text.index("INSERT")
```

The above will return a string of the form . (eg: "1.0", "2.0", "3.42", etc).

You can also add modifiers to an index. For example, if you want to go from "12.0" to "12.1" without hard-coding "12.1", you can do something like this:

```
text.tag_add("highlight", "12.0", "12.0+1c")
```

The latter is shorthand for "12.0 plus one character".

While it's very inefficient to do it this way, you could write your loop like so:

```
start_index = text.index(INSERT)
text.insert(INSERT, x)
for i in range(len(x)):
    text.tag_add('highlight',
                 f"{start_index}+{i}c",
                 f"{start_index}+{i+1}c"
)
```

The more efficient solution would be to skip the loop and highlight the whole line at once:

```
text.tag_add('highlight',
             f"{start_index}",
             f"{start_index}+{len(x)}c"
)
```

And finally, the most efficient would be to add the tag at the time of the insert statement:

```
text.insert(INSERT, x, 'highlight')
```

Comment: thanks for your time and solution. it is partially working but it is highlighting all characters in x.

Comment: @Naser: that's what your original code was doing. You can use the techniques in this answer to compute any text index you want.

Comment: just an irrelevant question. is it possible to use different colors in one Listbox using f string. for example:   user.insert(END, f'  hi(in red color) how are you (in green color)')

Comment: @Naser: no, it is not possible.